# Can an Entity access a Repository?

Tags: orm, repository, entity, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

Say I've got two simple entities: User and Review. How bad is it if User calls the Review repository? What is the "clean" way for the User to get its Reviews?

```
class User
{
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return reviewRepository.findByUser(this);
    }
}
```

I did have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827670/is-it-ok-for-entities-to-access-repositories), but although they say this is a bad practice, I didn't find an answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clean way in DDD is to have the UserRepository fill the reviews of the User when asking for a User.

```
class UserRepository
{
  public User GetUserByID(long userId)
  {
    var user = CreateUser();
    user.Reviews = FindReviewsforUser(userID);
    return user;
  }
}
```

But before you do this, you need to verify that your User Entity in your Domain is also an AggregateRoot! Only AggregateRoots have Repositories. Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836379/what-belongs-to-the-aggregate-root) to see or get some insights to the problems while desiging aggregateroots.

Comment: here is another usefull link for aggregates: http://thinkddd.com/blog/2009/02/14/aggregates-and-aggregate-roots/

Comment: Yes, both User and Review are aggregate roots. I like your solution, however what bothers me is: because `FindReviewsforUser()` is only called once when the User is instantiated, what happens if we add a new Review for that User? `User.Reviews` will be outdated, whereas it would have been up to date if we'd called the Repository again. Am I missing something?

Comment: You never will get full synchronization. At least not in a n-tier architecture! if you would do it like user.AddReview(review); your user object would be in sync (in a local environment).